# ORMLite SqlProcedure - how to tell the SP name?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm tring to use the SqlProcedure method but I see the first parameter as an anon object... I think it's for passing the parameters of the store but I don't see where to pass the SP name... what am I doing wrong?

```
   string sp = StoredProcedureHelper.Instance.GetStoreProcedureName("mySP");


           var dataTable =  dbConn.SqlProcedure<myPOCO>(new
            {
                ID_ISTITUTO = header.Istituto,
                ID_CANALE = header.MC_CHANNEL,
                OPERATORE = header.MC_USERID,
                NDG = header.MC_NDG,
                DOSSIER = header.Dossier
            });
```

where I specify the command text?

I'm under v4 Thanks

Comment: Does the t4 create a class to represent the stored procedure?

Comment: what you mean with t4? I've created my poco manually...

Comment: Sorry, read that as t4 templates instead of v4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **SqlList** to invoke custom SQL:

```
List<Poco> results = db.SqlList<Poco>("EXEC GetAnalyticsForWeek @weekNo", 
                                          new { weekNo = 1 });
```

via https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#new-apis-to-execute-custom-sql

and here are some unit tests for more examples

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/SqlServerProviderTests.cs

Comment: hello kampsj it not really what I was looking for since I wished to use the sqlprocedure<T>... i nave not fondo any docs on this

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `SqlProcedure` example [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/FirebirdTests/TestSimpleFirebirdProcedures/Main.cs)

You need to create a class to represent the parameter and alias it to the stored procedure name.

```
[Alias("SUB_TOT_BUDGET")]
public class ProcedureSubTotalBudgetParameters
{

    [Alias("HEAD_DEPT")]
    public string HeadDepartment
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

public class ProcedureSubTotalBudgetResult
{

    [Alias("TOT_BUDGET")]
    public decimal Total
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Alias("AVG_BUDGET")]
    public decimal Average
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Alias("MAX_BUDGET")]
    public decimal Max
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Alias("MIN_BUDGET")]
    public decimal Min
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

ProcedureSubTotalBudgetParameters p = new ProcedureSubTotalBudgetParameters() {
    HeadDepartment = "000"
};

var results = db.SqlProcedure<ProcedureSubTotalBudgetResult>(p, "");
```

Comment: Hell,o, I've read your implementation but this got a limitation...currently I've got a xml file that tells what SP to load (consider I want to point at a new SP with optimization and don't want to recompile), in this approach I can't since it's stoned in the class as attribute...

Comment: Maybe write a class to read the xml and return the correct stored procedure class